# How do I set the shell prompt in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

How do I set the shell prompt in Pycharm?

This is for Pycharm 2019.1.2.

I'm trying to set up the shell prompt so I can utilize existing set up code blocks in my scratch pad without a copy-paste. For reference to what I mean I I'm pulling a quote from *A Byte of Python*, which is what I'm learning from.

> You can see the version of Python on the screen by running:
>
> ```
> $ python3 -V
> Python 3.6.0
> ```
>
> NOTE: $ is the prompt of the shell. It will be different for you depending >on the settings of the operating system on your computer, hence I will >indicate the prompt by just the $ symbol.

I try running this and get an invalid syntax message:

```
$ python3 -v
  File "<input>", line 1
    $ python3 -v
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The author is simply using `$` to indicate that the following expression should be run in a shell. You should omit the prepended `$` when actually running the command.

Example:

`$ python3 -V`

Should be run as the following in your terminal.

`python3 -V`

As a follow up, the error message you posted above also looks like you are running this in the Python interpreter rather than your shell.

Comment: Thank you.

doing as you suggest get's me a `NameError: name 'python3' is not defined` when I do it as you show.

Considering I am in an interpreter does that mean I need to do something different?

Comment: Yes. `python3 -V` should be run outside the python interpreter. If you are are in the python interpreter (which you seem to be) you can exit it by running `quit()`; then try running `python3 -V`.

Comment: OK but when I'm in the interpreter how do I run the code block?

Comment: You can't invoke python inside the python interpreter. You simply shouldn't run that code block if you already in the interpreter.